# Alertbox with list selection items remains empty

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I would like to check a number of Spinner controls in the Onclick event of a few buttons (if the user moves away from the Activity), and if one or more were not filled out, display a warning message with 2 options to the user:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int i1 = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        (..)

    if ((i1 == 0) | (i2 == 0) | (i3 == 0) | (i4 == 0) | (i5 == 0)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("Answers missing, what do you want to do?");
        final CharSequence[] items = {
                "Oops.. let me fix that…",
                "I want to leave the app now" };
        alertbox.setTitle("Pick an item");
        alertbox.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 1) {
                                        finish();
                                      // should lead back to the spinner controls on the page

                }else if (item == 2){
                    finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process
                            .myPid());
                }
            }
        }).create();
        alertbox.show();
```

However, I just see an empty box with the title, but the message set with setMessage() is not displayed, and I don't get any list items for selection - the box is empty! Any idea what I can do to fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been having the same issue, and I found that if I remove the .setMessage line, then the list appears with the title.  Not sure why this is though.  If you use the .setpositive button, .negative, etc, then you can have a message.  I also noticed that google examples all don't use .setMessage with an item list.  They only use .setTitle, which doesn't give you that much space.
So, while this doesn't help you if you want a long message, it will get your list visible if that is your main goal.

Comment: great discovery, thanks! There seems to be a bit of a logical flaw with this function that "is not easy to grasp intuitively"... 8-)

Comment: Ugh can't believe this is the case!